# Is there a way to see the code in an answer in full screen or pop it out?

Tags: support, code-formatting

In general the size given for the answers it is just right, but some times there are answers with lots of code that is rather hard to see.

I was wondering if maybe i am missing some functionality to deal with that, I have seen in some sites sometimes you can popup the code in a separate window or see it in full screen.

I am using IE 8 (not my choice) and sometimes some of the javascript doesn't work well. That is why I ask here. Sorry if is a foolish question.

Thanks!

PS: I am not sure what is the appropiate tag for this question either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no functionality to expand the view of a block of code in a question or answer.

You'll need to copy the code to another location (a code/text editor, for example) if the browser's display is too small for you.

We don't want to encourage large blocks of code on SO posts.  It's generally a sign that the questions are either too broad, or haven't focused the code to specifically what is causing a problem.

Comment: My only gripe with the current code window is scroll bars.  Especially horizontal ones.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Agreed.  I think you shouldn't be allowed to post code if it would scroll horizontally and just force you to fix it before you can post the code.

Comment: Well, I agree that is better if answers are not too long. But I agree with @RobertHarvey too, for example in WPF with all the Dependency Property clutter it seems rather hard not winding up using scrollbars all over the place.